# BERTopic Embeddings ValueError when transform a new text

Tags: python-3.x, bert-language-model, topic-modeling, sentence-transformers

I have created embeddings using SentenceTransformer and trained a BERTopic model on those embeddings.

```
sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
embeddings = sentence_model.encode(training_docs, show_progress_bar=True)
topic_model = BERTopic().fit_transform(training_docs, embeddings)
topic_model.reduce_topics(training_docs, nr_topics=5)
```

I have then saved the `embeddings` using pickle and topic_model using `topic_model.save()`. I can also load them both but when I try to use it on a new text such as:

```
with open('embeddings.pickle', 'rb') as pkl:
    embeddings = pickle.load(pkl)

topic_model = BERTopic.load('mybertopic')

sentence = 'I have found my car.'

topics, probs = topic_model.transform(sentence, embeddings)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Make sure that the embeddings are a numpy array with shape: (len(docs), vector_dim) where vector_dim is the dimensionality of the vector embeddings.
```

The embeddings are a numpy array. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I solved it. I have to encode my text using the same SentenceTransformer and not use the entire embeddings in `transform` method.

```
embeddings = sentence_model.encode(sentence)
topics, probs = topic_model.transform(sentence, embeddings)
print(topics)
[-1]
```